# list of binary radio buttons tick all following when one is ticked

Tags: jquery

I want to write a list of binary radio buttons (left, right) 15 lines long.

Once a radio button on the left is ticked (like line 8) I want all radio buttons on the right side < line 8 be ticked and all left side right radio buttons > line 8 be ticked.

Could you point me in the right direction?

```
<form action="" method="post" role="form" class="form" id="form" onsubmit="return markFormSubmitted()"><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='32CPQSS1vecbL2RH5gIj8dJvG8NPFcOk' />
<input type="hidden" value="/p/sugizote/discounting/ChoicesOne/1/" name="origin_url" />
<table>
<tr><td> 
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_0_1"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_0_1" value="A" name="quarterlist_0" required> A</label>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_0_2"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_0_2" value="B" name="quarterlist_0" required> B</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_1_1"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_1_1" value="A" name="quarterlist_1" required> A</label>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_1_2"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_1_2" value="B" name="quarterlist_1" required> B</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_2_1"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_2_1" value="A" name="quarterlist_2" required> A</label>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_2_2"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_2_2" value="B" name="quarterlist_2" required> B</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_3_1"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_3_1" value="A" name="quarterlist_3" required> A</label> 
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_3_2"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_3_2" value="B" name="quarterlist_3" required> B</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_4_1"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_4_1" value="A" name="quarterlist_4" required> A</label>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_4_2"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_4_2" value="B" name="quarterlist_4" required> B</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_5_1"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_5_1" value="A" name="quarterlist_5" required> A</label>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_5_2"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_5_2" value="B" name="quarterlist_5" required> B</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_6_1"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_6_1" value="A" name="quarterlist_6" required> A</label>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_6_2"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_6_2" value="B" name="quarterlist_6" required> B</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_7_1"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_7_1" value="A" name="quarterlist_7" required> A</label>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_7_2"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_7_2" value="B" name="quarterlist_7" required> B</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_8_1"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_8_1" value="A" name="quarterlist_8" required> A</label>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_8_2"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_8_2" value="B" name="quarterlist_8" required> B</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_9_1"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_9_1" value="A" name="quarterlist_9" required> A</label>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_9_2"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_9_2" value="B" name="quarterlist_9" required> B</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_10_1"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_10_1" value="A" name="quarterlist_10" required> A</label>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_10_2"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_10_2" value="B" name="quarterlist_10" required> B</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_11_1"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_11_1" value="A" name="quarterlist_11" required> A</label>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_11_2"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_11_2" value="B" name="quarterlist_11" required> B</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_12_1"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_12_1" value="A" name="quarterlist_12" required> A</label>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_12_2"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_12_2" value="B" name="quarterlist_12" required> B</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_13_1"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_13_1" value="A" name="quarterlist_13" required> A</label>
<label class="radio-inline" for="id_quarterlist_13_2"><input type="radio" id="id_quarterlist_13_2" value="B" name="quarterlist_13" required> B</label>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

The output should look like this:
[Binary Radio button list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCb1L.png)

I don't have a starting point for jquery, what to use to achieve this.

Thx.

Comment: what you have tried? share your code

Comment: Sorry I hadn't finished the html, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with a lot of tinkering.
For anyone searching, here is the code.
If you check a field on the left side (A), all right sides (B)s are checked up to the clicked one and all left sides (A)s from there up to the last.

```
<table>
  <tr style="background:#3a3a3a;color:#ffffff"><td><b>Option A</b> </td><td><b>A</b></td><td><b>B</b></td><td><b>Option B</b></td></tr>
  <tr><td>in Woche <b>1</b></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="0" value="1" name="quarterlist_0" onClick="left_click(this.id)" required></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="0" value="2" name="quarterlist_0" onClick="right_click(this.id)" required></td>
    <td>wird in Woche <b>1</b> beginnen und wird (nach) Woche <b>13</b> enden</td></tr>
  <tr><td>in Woche <b>1</b></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="1" value="1" name="quarterlist_1" onClick="left_click(this.id)" required></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="1" value="2" name="quarterlist_1" onClick="right_click(this.id)" required></td>
    <td>wird in Woche <b>2</b> beginnen und wird (nach) Woche <b>13</b> enden</td></tr>
  {% for i in player.ranging %}
  <tr><td>wird in Woche <b>1</b> beginnen und wird (nach) Woche <b>{{i}}</b> enden</td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="{{i}}" value="1" name="quarterlist_{{i}}" onClick="left_click(this.id)" required></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="{{i}}" value="2" name="quarterlist_{{i}}" onClick="right_click(this.id)" required></td>
    <td>wird in Woche <b>{{i|add:1}}</b> beginnen und wird (nach) Woche <b>13</b> enden </td></tr>
{% endfor %}
  <tr><td>wird in Woche <b>1</b> beginnen und wird (nach) Woche <b>12</b> enden</td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="12" value="1" name="quarterlist_12" onClick="left_click(this.id)" required></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="12" value="2" name="quarterlist_12" onClick="right_click(this.id)" required></td><td>in Woche <b>13</b></td></tr>
  <tr><td>wird in Woche <b>1</b> beginnen und wird (nach) Woche <b>13</b> enden</td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="13" value="1" name="quarterlist_13" onClick="left_click(this.id)" required></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="13" value="2" name="quarterlist_13" onClick="right_click(this.id)" required></td>
    <td>in Woche <b>13</b></td></tr>

</table>
<br><br>

<script type="text/javascript">
function left_click(clicked_id){
    var varId = parseInt(clicked_id, 10);
    i = 0;
    while(i < varId){
        var but = [':radio[id=',i,'][value=2]'];
        var but = but.join("");
        $(but).prop('checked',true);
        i++;
    }
    i = varId;
    while(i < 14){
        var but = [':radio[id=',i,'][value=1]'];
        var but = but.join("");
        $(but).prop('checked',true);
        i++;
    }
}
function right_click(clicked_id){
    var varId = parseInt(clicked_id, 10);
    i = 0;
    j = varId++;
    while(i < j){
        var but = [':radio[id=',i,'][value=2]'];
        var but = but.join("");
        $(but).prop('checked',true);
        i++;
    }
    i = varId++;
    while(i < 14){
        var but = [':radio[id=',i,'][value=1]'];
        var but = but.join("");
        $(but).prop('checked',true);
        i++;
    }
}
</script>
```